# Not able to add XPath in @Given annotation in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, serenity-bdd

I am trying to use the @Given annotation for the Web Element identification.But when i enter as @Given(XPath=="") then it is throwing an error as XPath is not a variable or method.I tried to import different library as well but it is still throwing an Error.

Comment: I am using pageFactory of serenity for @Given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Given` is annotation to describe a test step in serenity I suppose. To locate and element using `PageFactory` you should use `@Findby`. Correct me if I am wrong as I haven't worked closely with `Serenity`.

Comment: Yes Correct.But when i write @FindBy(XPath="") then it is giving an error as not able to resolve method XPath.Thanks.

Comment: Are you using `@FindBy(Xpath="")` or `@FindBy(xpath="")`. `xpath` should be in small letters. Can you paste some line of your code for better lookout ?

Comment: I tried with small case xpath and it is working now.Thanks a lot. :)